# quickwatch on COM-objects does not show any information

Tags: arcobjects, .net, arcgis-10.6

While debugging my ArcObjects-code using VS2015 and .NET 4.5 I often try to inspect the data from my geodatabase.

So for example see this code:

```
public static bool PointsAreCollinear(IPoint from, IPoint intermediate, IPoint to, double tolsquare)
{
    // We compare the distance of the intermediate Point from the line between from and to.
    // (intermediate-from)*perp = dist * len
    // where perp is a vector perpendicular to (to-from) and len is it's length.
    // In order to avoid square roots, we prefer calculating the squares

    double tx = to.X - from.X;
    double ty = to.Y - from.Y;
    double hx = intermediate.X - from.X;
    double hy = intermediate.Y - from.Y;

    double lenSq = tx * tx + ty * ty;
    double dByLen = hx * ty - hy * tx;
    double dByLenSq = dByLen * dByLen;

    return dByLenSq <= lenSq * tolsquare;
}
```

When I add a watch to `to` for example it gives me this annoying info. From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467025/enable-native-code-debugging-to-deep-into-com-object) I suppose we could get the information for all the properties that are actually used within my source-code. All the rest is omitted while generating the interop-types for COM-objects. However as you can see I actually *do* use `to.X`, which is why I supposed that I could at least see its value within my quickwatch.

The suggestion from the mentioned post was to use the "Dynamic view" which depends on `IDispatch.GetTypeInfo()`. However that didn´t help neither.

Did anyone else ever had this problem when debugging ArcObjects?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some weeks we finally found an easy solution to re-enable that feature for .NET 4.x:

In Visual Studio under Tools-->Options-->Debugging enable the option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".